# Python 2.7: Keep only specific lists in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using `python 2.7` and I have a list that contains lists.

Here is my list:

```
range_list=[['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_192x144_15_qp_26_ON_encoder_randomaccess_B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt', 26, 35.1782, 136.8125, 300.788, 0.844, -3.5, '192x144'],
['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_192x144_25_qp_26_ON_encoder_randomaccess_B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt', 26, 35.1782, 228.0208, 302.251, 0.962, -2.5, '192x144'],
['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_384x288_15_qp_28_ON_encoder_randomaccess_B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt', 28, 35.2193, 275.4614, 1065.412, 2.167, -2, '384x288'],
['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_384x288_25_qp_28_ON_encoder_randomaccess_B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt', 28, 35.2193, 459.1024, 1064.403, 2.771, -1, '384x288'],
['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_720x576_15_qp_30_ON_encoder_randomaccess_B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt', 30, 35.5282, 484.3387, 3536.937, 6.679, 1.5, '720x576'],
['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_720x576_25_qp_30_ON_encoder_randomaccess_B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt', 30, 35.5282, 807.2312, 3553.744, 6.637, 2.5, '720x576']]
```

I want to keep only lists that contain the string  `_25_` in the first row.

For example the new list must be:

```
range_list1 = [['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_192x144_25_qp_26_ON_encoder_randomaccess_B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt', 26, 35.1782, 228.0208, 302.251, 0.962, -2.5, '192x144'],
['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_384x288_25_qp_28_ON_encoder_randomaccess_B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt', 28, 35.2193, 459.1024, 1064.403, 2.771, -1, '384x288'],
['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_720x576_25_qp_30_ON_encoder_randomaccess_B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt', 30, 35.5282, 807.2312, 3553.744, 6.637, 2.5, '720x576']]
```

Comment: So what does not work?

Comment: @SergeyVasilyev I did not know a proper solution to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple list comprehension:

```
[s for s in range_list if '_25_' in s[0]]
```

I have also changed the name of your list since `range` is a function.

Comment: I fit this code to my script using: `range_list1.append([s for s in range_list if '_25_' in s[0]])`

Comment: @zinon you can directly assign the result to a variable. `range_list1 = [s for s in range_list if '_25_' in s[0]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
newlist = []
#renamed the list to rangeVar
for i in rangeVar:
    if '25' in i[0]:
        newlist.append(i)


print newlist
```

output

```
[['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_192x144_25_qp_26_ON_encoder_randomaccess_B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt', 26, 35.1782, 228.0208, 302.251, 0.962, -2.5, '192x144'], ['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_384x288_25_qp_28_ON_encoder_randomaccess_B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt', 28, 35.2193, 459.1024, 1064.403, 2.771, -1, '384x288'], ['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_720x576_25_qp_30_ON_encoder_randomaccess_B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt', 30, 35.5282, 807.2312, 3553.744, 6.637, 2.5, '720x576']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple loop :

```
new_list=[]
for i in range_1:
    if '_25_' in i[0]:
        new_list.append(i)

print(new_list)
```

list comprehension :

```
print([i for i in range_1 if '_25_' in i[0]])
```

> additional information :

list comprehension `new_list=[i for i in range_1]` is same as :

```
new_list=[]
for i in range_1:
    new_list.append(i)
```

using generator expression :

```
print(list((i for i in range_1 if '_25_' in i[0])))
```